# How to reduce the dimensions of an array in R

Tags: arrays, r, merge, apply, dimensions

I have an array with 4 dimensions `c(12000, 100, 20, 4)` and I would like to merge two dimensions in one (the second and the third) to create a new array with 3 dimensions `c(12000, 2000, 4)`.

When using 2 dimensions array, the function I use is `as.vector`, but I'm stuck for bigger arrays. Is there a function like `apply`?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sample data:

```
x <- array(1:(12000*100*20*4), dim=c(12000, 100, 20, 4))
dim(x)

[1] 12000   100    20     4
```

Use `wrap` from `R.utils` to merge all dimensions (`NA`) except for 1 and 4:

```
library(R.utils)
y <- wrap(x, map=list(1, NA, 4))
dim(y)

[1] 12000   2000    4
```